# How do I run a Cloud Code on Heroku?

Tags: ios, swift, heroku, parse-cloud-code, parse-server

With the Parse's announcement of their retirement, I have migrated my Parse Server onto Heroku. With my still neophyte knowledge of Heroku, I do not know if they have a similar function to that of Cloud Code, but I do know that a few months ago [Parse Introduced a Heroku + Parse](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/introducing-heroku-parse/) feature that allows you to run Cloud Code on any node.js environment, particularly Heroku.

My dilemma is, I have already migrated my server from parse to Heroku prior to learning about this feature :/ , so I cannot run any parse cloud code form my terminal because there is no existing server there anymore. So the question is, how can I emulate this following Cloud Code in Heroku & How do I adjust my swift?

**Cloud Code:**

```
// Use Parse.Cloud.define to define as many cloud functions as you want.
// For example:

Parse.Cloud.define("isLoginRedundant", function(request, response) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var sessionQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Session);
    sessionQuery.equalTo("user", request.user);
    sessionQuery.find().then(function(sessions) {
        response.success( { isRedundant: sessions.length>1 } );
    }, function(error) {
        response.error(error);
    });
});
```

**and here is my swift back in xcode:**

```
    PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(userName!, password: passWord!) {
        (user, error) -> Void in
        if (user != nil) {
            // don't do the segue until we know it's unique login
            // pass no params to the cloud in swift (not sure if [] is the way to say that)
            PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("isLoginRedundant", withParameters: [:]) {
                (response: AnyObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                let dictionary = response as! [String:Bool]
                var isRedundant : Bool
                isRedundant = dictionary["isRedundant"]!
                if (isRedundant) {
                    // I think you can adequately undo everything about the login by logging out
                    PFUser.logOutInBackgroundWithBlock() { (error: NSError?) -> Void in
                        // update the UI to say, login rejected because you're logged in elsewhere
                        // maybe do a segue here? 
                        let redundantSession: String = "you are already logged in on another device"
                        self.failedMessage(redundantSession)

                        self.activityIND.stopAnimating()

                        self.loginSecond.userInteractionEnabled = true
                    }
                } else {
                    // good login and non-redundant, do the segue 
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginSuccess", sender: self) 
                } 
            } 
        } else {
            // login failed for typical reasons, update the UI 
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

                self.activityIND.stopAnimating()

                self.loginSecond.userInteractionEnabled = true

                if let message = error?.userInfo["error"] as? String
                    where message == "invalid login parameters" {
                        let localizedMessage = NSLocalizedString(message, comment: "Something isn't right, check the username and password fields and try again")
                        print(localizedMessage)
                        self.failedMessage(localizedMessage)
                }else if let secondMessage = error?.userInfo["error"] as? String
                    where secondMessage == "The Internet connection appears to be offline." {
                    self.failedMessage(secondMessage)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first checkout the [example repo](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example) and read the `parse-server` [documentation](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki). Parse server supports cloud code out of the box and you simply specify which file contains your functions and triggers in the parse-server config. The link you posted with the integration between parse and heroku is not relevant for `parse-server`.